# Late 50s comic: Lonely or Lost Planet; Earth is under occupation by green aliens wearing menacing helmets

Tags: story-identification, comics

I came here because I again thought of a comic book that I remember from the late 50s. It was about the planet Earth under occupation by alien powers (they were green, as I recall, and they had neat and menacing helmets and face plates).

Interestingly enough, while searching for that comic book, I saw a post from someone else who remembered the same plot but from the late 90s. I wanted to tell him what I knew, but in the process of signing up to this site again I lost his post.

I could be wrong about the date, but I'm 80, and I wasn't reading comic books in the 90s. I'm sure that it was in the 50s, because I joined the Army in 1956, and that was the end of my comic book days.

Comment: Hi there! What is the relation to a "lost and lonely planet"? Is that the title you recall? As per this other user's post - excuse me if I sound silly but maybe your browser history still has it? Last - could you check [these guidelines](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/98028), see if they trigger any more memories you could [edit] in? :)

Comment: [Lost Planet](https://comicvine.gamespot.com/lost-planet/4050-3885/)

Comment: [Robotmen of the Lost Planet](https://www.mycomicshop.com/search?TID=367131)

Answer (score 4):

*The Lost World* by "Thornecliffe Herrick" (house pseudonym) ran in [*Planet Comics*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planet_Comics) from issue #21 (November 1942) to issue #70 (Spring 1953). Earth has been devastated and conquered by the Volta men, space Nazis with wrinkly green skin and spiked helmets. [Hunt Bowman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hunt_Bowman) leads the resistance, armed with bow and arrows and accompanied by Lyssa, Queen of Mars. You can read them all for free at [Comic Books Plus](http://comicbookplus.com/?dlid=39936).

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hunt_Bowman#Fictional_history):

> Hunt Bowman lived on a future Earth that had been conquered by the Voltamen, fierce reptilian creatures that were initially depicted as short and orange, but later became tall with green skin. He is a giant of a man, massively strong, and highly skilled with a [bow and arrow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bow_and_arrow). He is discovered living on Earth by Lyssa, the Queen of Mars, when she leads an exploration party onto that planet. She takes him to Mars with her, then they return to Earth, where they gradually develop a [resistance movement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resistance_movement) against the Voltaman.

Answer (score 1):

The *Eagle* comic included a Dan Dare story *Reign of the Robots*, in which Dare and Co return from an interstellar voyage to find Earth occupied by the green-skinned Treens from Venus. That was late 1950s iirc.

The Earth was policed by mechanical "electrobots", while on Venus the same job was done by more formidable "selektrobots", each controlled from a satellite. Hence the title.